# Confusion regarding the derivative of $y=\arccos\big({\frac{2x}{1+x^2}}\big)$

Tags: derivatives

[image]Find the derivative of the following function without substitution with respect to $x:$

$y=\arccos\big({\frac{2x}{1+x^2}}\big)$

I solved it without substitution and found its derivative as $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{2}{1+x^2},$ but the real answer is $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{-2}{1+x^2}.$

Where am I getting wrong?
Any guidance would be highly appreciated!
Thank you!

Edit:
My steps of solution is posted below as an image:

Comment: @AnneBauval sir,I have just posted my steps.Would you check the solution now?Sorry for delay!

Comment: All this is for $|x|<1,$ hence $\sqrt{(x^2-1)^2}$ is equal to $1-x^2,$ not $x^2-1.$

Comment: @AnneBauval thank you so much sir!

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/34121/468350

Answer (score 2):

Actually the function $\,f(x)=\arccos\left(\dfrac{2x}{1+x^2}\right)\,$ is defined and continuous on $\,(-\infty,+\infty)\,$ and it is differentiable on $\,(-\infty,+\infty)\setminus\{-1,+1\}\,.$

For any $\,x\in\Bbb R\,\land\,x\neq-1\,\land\,x\neq1\,$ it results that

$\require{cancel}\begin{align}f’(x)&=-\dfrac1{\sqrt{1-\dfrac{4x^2}{\left(1+x^2\right)^2}}}\!\cdot\!\dfrac{2\left(1+x^2\right)-4x^2}{\left(1+x^2\right)^2}=\\[3pt]&=\dfrac{-1}{\sqrt{\dfrac{\left(1-x^2\right)^2}{\color{#8888FF}{\cancel{\color{black}{\left(1+x^2\right)^2}}}}}}\!\cdot\!\dfrac{2\left(1-x^2\right)}{\left(1+x^2\right)^{\color{#5555FF}{\cancel{\color{black}2}}}}=\dfrac{-2\left(1-x^2\right)}{\left|1-x^2\right|\left(1+x^2\right)}=\\[3pt]&=\begin{cases}\dfrac{-2}{1+x^2}&\quad\text{if }\;x\in(-1,1)\\[7pt]\dfrac2{1+x^2}&\quad\text{if }\;x\in(-\infty,-1)\cup(1,+\infty)\;.\end{cases}\end{align}$

Moreover ,

$\begin{align}\!\!\!\!\!\lim\limits_{x\to-1^-}f’(x)&=\!\!\!\lim\limits_{x\to-1^-}\!\dfrac2{1\!+\!x^2}=1\color{red}{\neq}-1=\!\!\!\lim\limits_{x\to-1^+}\!\dfrac{-2}{1\!+\!x^2}=\!\!\!\lim\limits_{x\to-1^+}f’(x)\;,\end{align}$

$\begin{align}\!\!\!\lim\limits_{x\to1^-}f’(x)&=\!\!\lim\limits_{x\to1^-}\dfrac{-2}{1+x^2}=-1\color{red}{\neq}1=\!\!\lim\limits_{x\to1^+}\dfrac2{1+x^2}=\!\!\lim\limits_{x\to1^+}f’(x)\;.\end{align}$

Since $\,f(x)\,$ is continuous on $\,(-\infty,+\infty)\,,\,$ differentiable on $\,(-\infty,+\infty)\setminus\{-1,+1\}\,$ and $\;\lim\limits_{x\to-1^-}f’(x)=1\,,\;$ $\lim\limits_{x\to-1^+}f’(x)=-1\,,\;$ $\lim\limits_{x\to1^-}f’(x)=-1\,,\;$ $\lim\limits_{x\to1^+}f’(x)=1\,,$

it follows that

$\exists f’_-(-1)=1\,,\;$ $\;\exists f’_+(-1)=-1\;,$
$\exists f’_-(1)=-1\,,\;$ $\;\exists f’_+(1)=1\;.$

Consequently, $\,\not\exists f’(-1)\,,\,$ $\not\exists f’(1)\,,\,$ that is , neither at $x=-1$ nor at $x=1$ the function $f(x)$ is differentiable, in fact the function $\,f(x)\,$ has a corner point at $\,x=-1\,$ and another corner point at $\,x=1\,.$

Here is the graph of the function $\,f(x)\,:$

[image]

**Addendum :**

It is not difficult to prove that

$f(x)=\arccos\left(\dfrac{2x}{1+x^2}\right)=\\[12pt]=\begin{cases}2\arctan x+\dfrac{3\pi}2=-2\mathrm{\,arccot\,}x+\dfrac{5\pi}2\;,&\forall x\!\in(-\infty,-1]\\[5pt]-2\arctan x+\dfrac{\pi}2=2\mathrm{\,arccot\,}x-\dfrac{\pi}2\;,&\forall x\!\in[-1,1]\\[5pt]2\arctan x-\dfrac{\pi}2=-2\mathrm{\,arccot\,}x+\dfrac{\pi}2\;,&\forall x\!\in[1,+\infty)\end{cases}$